# "foreach (var line in fileInfo)" Only reading the first line

Tags: c#, file, asynchronous, foreach

As I iterate through, my code it is only producing the first line of the text file.

I am stubborn on using a foreach loop but everything I have found has showed that this should be working.

```
    public void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
            openFileDialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
            openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
            DialogResult result = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
            path = openFileDialog.FileName;
            //checkedTb.Text = fileInfo;
            count = File.ReadLines(path).Count();
            // checkedTb.Text = path;
        }

    }

    public async void StartBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
        fileInfo = await reader.ReadLineAsync();

        foreach (var line in fileInfo)
        {
            checkedTb.Text += fileInfo;
        }
    }
```

I expect it to be able to read everything as that is what the 
"foreach (var line in fileInfo)" is supposed to be for. Thank you all for your time in advance! Much appreciated!

Comment: ReadLineAsync reads only one line. Put in inside the loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently you're iterating over every *character* within a single *line*. If you want to iterate over every *line* within the file, you want something like:

```
using (var reader = File.OpenText(path))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
    {
        // Use the line here
    }
}
```

Note that currently you're appending each line to `checkedTb.Text`, without the line break, so you'll end up with all the text from the file, but in a single line. If that's *not* what you want, you'll need to work out exactly what you *do* want in order to make the appropriate change.

Using a `foreach` loop (instead of a `while` loop) with asynchronous code is *currently* tricky, but will become easier in C# 8. You'll want something that returns an `IAsyncEnumerable<string>`, which you could potentially write yourself if the framework doesn't provide it. (I'd expect a `File.ReadLinesAsync` method at some point.) There's already `File.ReadAllLinesAsync` if you're happy to read the whole file in one go - that returns a `Task<string[]>`. You could use that as:

```
var lines = await File.ReadAllLinesAsync(path);
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    ...
}
```

However, if the file is very large, that may not be what you want in terms of showing progress as you read the file.

Answer (score 0):

This would more precise to use reader.ReadToEndAsync you get all contents of file, then you can iterate over each lines

```
public static async void Click()
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\Bhushan\a.txt");
            var fileContent = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
```